# Suppress warning of url in beautifulsoup

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I'm using Beautiful Soup 4 to parse some html-formatted text, scraped from the Internet. Sometimes this text is simply the link to some website. A fact that BS4 is very cross about:

```
UserWarning: "http://example.com" looks like a URL. Beautiful Soup is not
an HTTP client. You should probably use an HTTP client to get the document
behind the URL, and feed that document to Beautiful Soup.
```

I'm very aware of this fact, I just want to interpret the text input, not get a lecture. I use the console for monitoring the activities of the script, and it's being cluttered by a very angry library.

**Any way to suppress or disable this warning?**

Comment: Catch `UserWarning`.

Comment: @LutzHorn It's not an exception, its printing directly to the console, and it doesn't stop the execution of the program.

Comment: I agree with your observation the warning is very assuming regarding your intentions. If anyone was expecting BS4 to follow URL's, just let them look up the FAQ if they wonder why it's not working.

Answer (score 47):

To simply suppress the warning and continue with processing this works:

```
import warnings
from bs4 import UserWarning
warnings.filterwarnings("ignore", category=UserWarning, module='bs4')
```

Comment: You can avoid suppressing other Beautiful Soup warnings by adding a keyword argument like `message='.*looks like a URL.*'` to the `filterwarnings` call.

Comment: If you're specifying the message, you may also want this one: `looks like a filename, not markup.`.  What an odd use of the warning system.

Comment: `from bs4 import UserWarning` is required as well

Comment: Did something change in a recent version? I get `ImportError: cannot import name 'UserWarning' from 'bs4'`

Comment: Recent version update: Replace 'UserWarning' with 'MarkupResemblesLocatorWarning'

```from bs4 import BeautifulSoup, MarkupResemblesLocatorWarning
warnings.filterwarnings('ignore', category=MarkupResemblesLocatorWarning)```

Comment: @RahulMadhavan's comment worked for me. Note that we're also omitting `module='bs4'`.